# javafx adding all subtotal of all column in tableview

Tags: javafx

I have `Tableview` here  that allows me to multiply the price and the quantity and put that into the subtotal column my question is i want to get the sum of all the subtotals for all the items in the table , thanks

```
private TableView<Product> table = new TableView<Product>();
private final ObservableList<Product> data =
        FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new Product("Notebook", 10, 12),
                new Product("Eraser", 20, 12),
                new Product("Pencil", 30, 12),
                new Product("Pen", 40, 12),
                new Product("Glue", 50, 12));
final HBox hb = new HBox();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) {
    Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
    stage.setTitle("Book Store Sample");
    stage.setWidth(650);
    stage.setHeight(550);

    final Label label = new Label("Book Store");
    label.setFont(new Font("Arial", 20));

    table.setEditable(true);


    TableColumn name = new TableColumn("Name");
    name.setMinWidth(100);
    name.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("name"));
    name.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.forTableColumn());
    name.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, String>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, String> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setName(t.getNewValue());
                }
            }
    );


    TableColumn priceCol = new TableColumn("Price");
    priceCol.setMinWidth(100);
    priceCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("price"));
    priceCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Product, Number>forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
    priceCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, Number>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, Number> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setPrice(t.getNewValue().intValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn quantityCol = new TableColumn("Quantity");
    quantityCol.setMinWidth(200);
    quantityCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, Number>("quantity"));
    quantityCol.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<Product, Number>forTableColumn(new NumberStringConverter()));
    quantityCol.setOnEditCommit(
            new EventHandler<CellEditEvent<Product, Number>>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(CellEditEvent<Product, Number> t) {
                    ((Product) t.getTableView().getItems().get(
                            t.getTablePosition().getRow())
                    ).setQuantity(t.getNewValue().intValue());
                }
            }
    );

    TableColumn subTotalCol = new TableColumn("Sub Total");
    subTotalCol.setMinWidth(200);
    subTotalCol.setCellValueFactory(
            new PropertyValueFactory<Product, String>("subTotal"));


    table.setItems(data);
    table.getColumns().addAll(name, priceCol, quantityCol, subTotalCol);

    final TextField addName = new TextField();
    addName.setPromptText("Name");
    addName.setMaxWidth(name.getPrefWidth());
    final TextField addPrice = new TextField();
    addPrice.setMaxWidth(priceCol.getPrefWidth());
    addPrice.setPromptText("Price");
    final TextField addQuantity = new TextField();
    addQuantity.setMaxWidth(quantityCol.getPrefWidth());
    addQuantity.setPromptText("Quantity");

    final Button addButton = new Button("Add");
    addButton.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
            data.add(new Product(
                    name.getText(),
                    Integer.parseInt(addPrice.getText()),
                    Integer.parseInt(addQuantity.getText())));
            addName.clear();
            addPrice.clear();
            addQuantity.clear();
        }
    });

    hb.getChildren().addAll(addName, addPrice, addQuantity, addButton);
    hb.setSpacing(3);

    final VBox vbox = new VBox();
    vbox.setSpacing(5);
    vbox.setPadding(new Insets(10, 0, 0, 10));
    vbox.getChildren().addAll(label, table, hb);

    ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().addAll(vbox);

    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

public static class Product {

    private final SimpleStringProperty name;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty price;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty quantity;
    private final SimpleIntegerProperty subTotal;

    private Product(String name, int price, int quantity) {
        this.name = new SimpleStringProperty(name);
        this.price = new SimpleIntegerProperty(price);
        this.quantity = new SimpleIntegerProperty(quantity);
        this.subTotal = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        NumberBinding multiplication = Bindings.multiply(this.priceProperty(), this.quantityProperty());
        this.subTotalProperty().bind(multiplication);
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.get();
    }

    public SimpleStringProperty nameProperty() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name.set(name);
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty priceProperty() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price.set(price);
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return quantity.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty quantityProperty() {
        return quantity;
    }

    public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
        this.quantity.set(quantity);
    }

    public int getSubTotal() {
        return subTotal.get();
    }

    public SimpleIntegerProperty subTotalProperty() {
        return subTotal;
    }

    public void setSubTotal(int subTotal) {
        this.subTotal.set(subTotal);
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I don't quite understand "all the subtotals if I put more than one list of subtotals"? Are you saying you have further properties in your `Product` class that aren't shown, and you want to get the totals? Or do you want to get the sum of all the subtotals for all the items in the table?

Comment: i mean i want to get the sum of all the subtotals for all the items in the table . i'm sorry for my complicated question .

Comment: Please edit the question to make it clearer. That way it will be more useful to other people. (You do not have "more than one list of subtotals", whatever that means.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a binding that tracks the total of all the subtotal values:

```
IntegerBinding total = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> 
    table.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Product::getSubTotal)),
    table.getItems());
```

The first parameter to this is a function that computes the total of the results of calling `product.getSubTotal()` on each element in `table.getItems()`. The second argument ensures that this binding is marked as invalid (so can be recomputed) any time `table.getItems()` is invalidated.

Using the default mechanism of constructing a list, as you do with `ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableArrayList(...)`, the list will only be invalidated when items are added, removed, or replaced, but not if the `subTotal` of an existing item changes. To make this happen, you need to modify that line to use a [`extractor`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-):

```
private final ObservableList<Product> data = FXCollections.observableList(Arrays.asList(
    new Product("Notebook", 10, 12),
    new Product("Eraser", 20, 12),
    new Product("Pencil", 30, 12),
    new Product("Pen", 40, 12),
    new Product("Glue", 50, 12)),
    product -> new Observable[] {product.subTotalProperty()});
```

Now you can do something like

```
Label totalLabel = new Label();
totalLabel.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Total: %d", total));
```

*Update*

Here is what the `IntegerBinding` code looks like without a lambda expression, though it is far less clear and I don't recommend doing this:

```
IntegerBinding total = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(new Callable<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer call() {
        return table.getItems().stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(
            new ToIntFunction<Product>() {
                @Override
                public int applyAsInt(Product product) {
                    return product.getSubTotal();
                }
            }));
    }
}, table.getItems());
```

Comment: is that a lambda expression ?

Comment: `product -> new Observable[] { ... }` is a lambda expression.

Comment: and the IntegerBinding total = Bindings.createIntegerBinding(() -> ? right ? i mean the truth is i don't know yet what is totally a lambda expression and  the thing that i know in lambda expression is when you make the code shorter than the usual it is. am i right ? can you show the code that is not written in lambda expression ?

Comment: Yes, that's a lambda expression too. You can easily replace them with implementations of `Callable` and `Callback` if you need. The [Java tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) has a pretty full explanation of lambdas, but basically they just replace an anonymous inner class implementation of an interface with a single method. (So you just have the method implementation instead of all the plumbing.)

Comment: Added the code for the `IntegerBinding` without using lambdas. I'd be very surprised if you found that somehow clearer.

Comment: i think lambda is more better of what i see right now . you can write the code shorter .

Comment: this syntax product -> new Observable[] {product.subTotalProperty()}); it say's that the SimpleIntegerProperty cann0t be c0nverted  t0 0bservabe

Comment: Looks like you have the wrong import for Observable

Comment: one last thing . can i use the IntegerBinding total to be deducted by the received cash ? and get the cash change . i tried this if (received cash - alltotal) but the error say's that bad operand types for binary operator "-" i know that they are not compatible because the one is int and the second is IntegerBinding is there any conversion for this ?

Comment: Check the [Javadocs for `IntegerBinding`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/IntegerBinding.html). It inherits a [`subtract` method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/NumberExpression.html#subtract-javafx.beans.value.ObservableNumberValue-) (actually several `subtract(...)` methods taking different parameter types).

Comment: can i do double binding while getting the value in textfield ? and use it in DoubleBinding?

Comment: I think that sounds like a different question to the original question you posted here. I'd recommend you look at the java docs and try some things. If you can't get what you want to work, post a new question...